# PHPUnit test returning null at each index of array

Tags: php, phpunit

I am testing a function in PHP that sorts modules by their marks in descending order where it takes in an array of the module names and another array of the module marks. However, when I am testing it, it returns null at each index of the array.

For example, here is my Unit test:

```
public function testCorrect()
{
    $this->assertEquals(["Computer Science",60,"Religion",50, "English",40, "Business",30, "Maths",20], 
    getSortedModules(["Maths","Business","English","Religion","Computer Science"],[20,30,40,50,60]));
}
```

I don't get the expected return but instead get:

```
+    0 => Array (...)
+    1 => Array (...)
+    2 => Array (...)
+    3 => Array (...)
+    4 => Array (...)
```

The function getSortedModules seems to work correctly in the frontend of my system but the code for it is:

```
function getSortedModules($modules, $marks)
{
$module_marks = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++) {
  $module_marks_array = array("module"=>$modules[$i], "marks"=>$marks[$i]);
  array_push($module_marks,$module_marks_array);
}
usort($module_marks, function($a, $b) {
      return $b['marks'] <=> $a['marks'];
});

return $module_marks;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't build the values the way you are testing them.  It builds each item as `module` and `marks` elements in an array and sorts them.  So the value it's returning is what I would expect, not sure if it's your test that is wrong.

Comment: I thought if the parameters were passed then the code in the function executes and from there I get a result.